# Apex based sharing Record

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

I have created custom object (Test) which contains (name ,phone number and email fields)and the records inside the test object only visible to the my team leader and his manager..other user,leader and manager cannot view those record in test objects.
for that I've created Apex trigger:

```
trigger Test_Share on Test__c (after insert) {

    Id i = UserInfo.getUserId();

    //ID groupId = [select id from Group where Type = 'Organization'].id;

    if (trigger.isInsert) {

        List<Test__Share> testShare = new List<Test__Share>();
        for (Test__c t : trigger.new) {

            Test__Share ts = new Test__Share();

            ts.ParentId = t.Id;
            ts.UserOrGroupId = ParrentIdClass.getParrentId(i);

            ts.AccessLevel = 'edit';

            ts.RowCause = Schema.Test__Share.RowCause.Test_Access__c;
            testShare.add(ts);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] TestShareInsertResult = Database.insert(testShare, false);
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public class ParrentIdClass {

public static Id getParrentId(Id i) {
    String ParentUserName;
    Id ParentUserId;
    User u = new User(id = i);
    u = [select u.UserRoleId from User u where u.Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];

    System.debug('UserRoleId=' + u.UserRoleId);


    UserRole ur = new UserRole(id = u.UserRoleId);
    ur = [select ur.Id, ur.Name, ur.ParentRoleId from UserRole ur where ur.Id = : u.UserRoleId];


    System.debug('UrId=' + ur.Id);
    System.debug('UrName=' + ur.Name);
    System.debug('UrParentRoleId=' + ur.ParentRoleId);


    if (ur.ParentRoleId != null) {
        //  check if there's a ParentRole
        UserRole ur1 = new UserRole(id = ur.ParentRoleId);
        ur1 = [select ur1.Id, ur1.Name, ur1.ParentRoleId from UserRole ur1 where ur1.Id = : ur.ParentRoleId];
        System.debug('UrId=' + ur1.Id);
        System.debug('UrName=' + ur1.Name);
        System.debug('UrParentRoleId=' + ur1.ParentRoleId);
        if (ur1.ParentRoleId != null) {
            //  last level in the hierarchy
            UserRole ur2 = new UserRole(id = ur1.ParentRoleId);
            ur2 = [select ur2.Id, ur2.Name, ur2.ParentRoleId from UserRole ur2 where ur2.Id = : ur1.ParentRoleId];
            System.debug('UrId=' + ur2.Id);
            System.debug('UrName=' + ur2.Name);
            System.debug('UrParentRoleId=' + ur2.ParentRoleId);
            ParentUserId = ur2.Id;
            return ParentUserId;
        } else {
            // no more ParentRoleId
            ParentUserId = ur1.Id;
            return ParentUserId;
        }
    } else {
        // no ParentRoleId
        ParentUserId = ur.Id;
        return ParentUserId;
    }
}
```

}

But it doesnt work for my scenario..
like if user creates a record then it is not visible to his team leader...but it is visble to manager..
Can anyone tell me logi for this scenario

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have grant access using hierarchy checked on the object then this is not needed correct? When you say does not work what exactly do you mean....Any error message or is the access you desire not provided. What specific access are you looking to grant -> sibling roles -> roles at the same level, etc

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? We need symptoms to diagnose the cause.

Comment: Hy it doesnt visble team leader if team member creates a record on test object...for that what I have to do??/

Comment: How is a Team Leader related to a User.  How is User's Manager related to the User in Salesforce?